# Google Ad blocking onload event

Tags: html, onload, adsense

Why is the following html prohibiting the onload event from being triggered? If I comment out the google ad code then the event is indeed fired. I've only tested in firefox 15.0 on Mac Os X.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function load()
            {
               alert("Hello")
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="load()">


     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    /* iKarta main */
    google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXX";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tested it on jsfiddle and on my server and it works just fine

Comment: The loading icon keeps spinning in the tab for the page associated with this code in firefox. What workarounds might I try?

Comment: Your code works just fine in FF15 .

Comment: The code works on my server actually, but not locally on my machine. Why is that?